# Fourier motzkin elimination

Tags: algorithm

I have implemented fm-elim in c using matrix.
I am wondering if following modification to the original algorithm is allowed or not?

In the original version of the algorithm one takes a row with positive coeff. in front of xr and subtracts it with the one with the negative coeff to create new equations. Matrix can grow in size.
see page 32-33  http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/Education/EDAF15/F07.pdf

But is it allowed to choose one equation with negative coeff and use gauss elim to eliminate the xr.
I tried solving some small system and it seems to give me correct answer but I don't know if this method is correct or not.
With this method my matrix won't grow in size. This way I will be doing ordinary gauss elimination.

Comment: Perhaps you're better off asking at http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would say if you can prove that a modification to a particular algorithm will always give you the same correct answer as the original, then it is certainly a valid modification to make. However, the result may be more or less efficient than the original, and it's probably not valid to call it by the name of the original, because it is no longer the original. But if it works, and you have good reason to do it, then modify away. Just make sure to call it a "modified version of XYZ algorithm" or some such, so people know that you're not talking about the original...

Comment: Thanks i will try to solve some more system to find out if it always works